# Applying Text to two tkinter RadioButtons

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to put two Radiobutton widgets into my tkinter GUI that will denote Male and Female, however when I implement the below code:

```
createGenderRBM=tk.Radiobutton(createFrame, text="Male",textvariable=gender,value="Male",font=labelFont)
createGenderRBM.grid(row=4,column=2)
createGenderRBF=tk.Radiobutton(createFrame, text="Female",textvariable=gender,value="Female",font=labelFont)
createGenderRBF.grid(row=4,column=3)
```

The "Male" and "Female text does not appear.

[image: T]

Comment: show rest of you code. In my tests i get proper display of text next to buttons

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi: that shouldn't be possible, if in your tests you copy this code exactly, and create a `StringVar` named `gender`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set `textvariable` to `gender`. Setting `textvariable` will override whatever you configured for `text`.  Thus, if the value of `gender` is an empty string, that's what will appear as the text of the radiobutton.

I don't know why you are setting `textvariable`, but my guess is that you want that variable to have the value of the radiobutton. If that's the case, change `textvariable` to `variable`.